# How to implement SMS/MMS read and send from other Android Phone using Java via Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to have Android app which helps to sync between 2 or more Androind mobile devices via Bluetooth using MAP(Message Access Profile).

From my research, MAP is consists of MNS and MAS, and MAS (Message Access service) can be used to get SMS/MMS and MNS (Message Notification service) can be used to get notified when there is new SMS/MMS.

[image]

The question is: How can I implement that Notify/Read/Send(aka Reply) functionality in Java using Bluetooth MAP?

Comment: I am not sure but I don't think Android have native BT MAP support so it would be up to you to implement the standard. The standard should be available on Bluetooth sig web site and how to implement BLE client and server can be found it a lot of tutorials and sample apps.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your information. Yes you are right. I can see detailed MAP profile specification in sig website. But I could not find any example in Java/Android yet. It is a bit difficult to figure out where to start.

Comment: BLE only has read, write and notification/indication. This is always the same for all protocols. So any BLE example will show you how to implement Bluetooth functionality, the rest is in the MAP specification.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your info. If possible, could you please share any example for BLE?
And could you let me know if BLE supports MAP too? From my research, it was not supported in BLE.

Comment: This one should work: https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/. If two Android device communicate with each other, each of them can implement any Bluetooth GATT service you want. It is a bit like implementing a HTTP server and HTTP client on top of TCP/IP. https://proandroiddev.com/android-bluetooth-as-a-service-c39c3d732e56

Comment: @Robert From my research, it seems be difficult to use MAP directly in Android Java. And it seems MAP is just abstract layer. I think I need to use BluetoothGattServer  / BluetoothGatt classes. What do you think?

Comment: Sorry but in your comment you contradict yourself. First you say you can not implement MAP in java and then you say to use BluetoothGattServer / BluetoothGatt classes (which are java classes and this is the correct way). Anyway as GATT client and server are both implemented by you you don't have to implement MAP, you can design your own protocol if MAP does not perfectly fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/bluetooth-message-access-profile-map.64322/#:~:text=%232,that%20allows%20you](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/bluetooth-message-access-profile-map.64322/#:%7E:text=%232,that%20allows%20you)

As direct implement in kotlin/java not possible may be.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36919258

[Message Access Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75409273/message-access-profile)

I also tried to find sample and code for MAP.

But unable to find any useful resources or demos.